# Prisma deploy embedded in two fields error like bug

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I would like to have two colums with the same type of data
`from`  and `to`

this is a very simple example about the error

`datamodel.prisma` file with a one columns `from: Address!`

```
            // it runs fine
            type Travel {
              id: ID! @id
              from: Address!
            }
            type Address @embedded {
              district: String!
            }
```

`datamodel.prisma` file with two field with the same embedded `from: Address!` `to: Address!`

```
            // it runs fine
            type Travel {
              id: ID! @id
              from: Address!
              to: Address!
            }
            type Address @embedded {
              district: String!
            }
```

It throws the error

```
            Errors:
              Travel
                ✖ The relation field `from` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
                ✖ The relation field `to` must specify a `@relation` directive: `@relation(name: "MyRelation")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Prisma's documentation on [Data Modeling](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/blob/master/docs/1.0/04-Reference/01-Service-Configuration/03-Data-Modelling-(SDL).md) (see also [Datamodel (MongoDB)](https://www.prisma.io/docs/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-MONGO-knun/) as your use of the `@embedded` directive hints that you might be using a document database), the `name` argument of the `@relation` directive is needed when your data model contains ambiguous relations.

In your example, there are two different relations between `Travel` and `Address!`, so it seems that Prisma wants you to disambiguate those.

A very similar question appears here (and has a more detailed answer than mine): [Can’t create two or more relations to User (from / to) on Event](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/cant-create-two-or-more-relations-to-user-from-to-on-event/2957).